# Android: Stop a function listen for a click and the resume

Tags: android, audio, thread-sleep

I have a function `playsounds()` which basically plays the same sound file again and again however with a different value of a `float` called "balance" each time. After each play, I want the function to stop and listen for a user click on a different `Button`. If there is no click the next play is called.

However, if the user clicks then I want to record that value of balance. My problem is that, once i start the function, there is no way to stop it in between. So even if I click, it gets unnoticed.

Could you help me in the problem ?

```
public void playsounds() throws InterruptedException
    { 

    snd.setBalance(0);
    snd.play(table);
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    tv.setText("Pressed at first call ");

    snd.setBalance(0.04f);
    snd.play(table);
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    tv.setText("Pressed at second call ");

    snd.setBalance(0.08f);
    snd.play(table);
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    tv.setText("and so on...");

    snd.setBalance(0.12f);
    snd.play(table);
    Thread.sleep(2000);

    snd.setBalance(0.16f);
    snd.play(table);
    Thread.sleep(2000);

    snd.setBalance(1.0f);
    snd.play(table);
    Thread.sleep(2000);

    snd.setBalance(1.84f);
    snd.play(table);
    Thread.sleep(2000);

    snd.setBalance(1.88f);
    snd.play(table);
    Thread.sleep(2000);

    snd.setBalance(1.92f);
    snd.play(table);
    Thread.sleep(2000);

    snd.setBalance(1.96f);
    snd.play(table);
    Thread.sleep(2000);    

    snd.setBalance(2.0f);
    snd.play(table);
    Thread.sleep(2000);     
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly... could you use a boolean value and just check it after you are done sleeping?

```
public class MyClass implements OnClickListener{

         private boolean buttonClick;

         public void playSounds(){
              //play sound
              // sleep
              if(buttonClick){
                  buttonClick = false;
                  //perform action or return
              }
         }

         public void onClick(){
              buttonClick = true;
         }
    }
```

Calling Thread.sleep() is probably not the best option if this is on the main thread, you will not be able to have instantaneous responses.  You could also make the function smaller and call it over and over.. something like

```
public void playSound(float fValue){
    snd.setBalance(fValue);
    snd.play(table);
    //sleep
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to effectively turn your program inside out, and make it entirely event driven.

Basically, you have a timer and the user as sources of events.  You have a variable that holds your current task state, and a to-do list of what you will do next.

You begin an operation from your to-do list, and start a timer for the period of time until you would next do something absent user input.

If you get user input, you cancel the timer if it has not yet run its TimerTask.  Based on the user input, you may modify your to-do list, record something, or set output.

If the TimerTask runs before you get user input, you just do the next thing on the list.

Since a TimerTask and user input happen on different threads, you'll need a mechanism to insure only one can be happening at a time.  A simple solution would be to have them both call a synchronized method which does the real work, supplying the type of event as a parameter.  An alternate idea would be to set a synchronized flag register recording the user input, then re-schedule the timer so that the TimerTask gets executed immediately thereafter, and have that handle the user input which it discoveres from the flag.